# Update row in a ListView in a fragment in a TabLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

As the confusing title said, I've an activity that contains a tablayout which is populated with a custom FragmentPagerAdapter. Each tab contains a ListView and each row in the ListView contains an image.

I want to be able to click a row and change the image for that row. I can change the value in the database no problem but the view won't update. Is there a way to change JUST the row's image without calling notifyDataSetChanged() (which doesn't work for me).

This question is the same as one I just asked an hour ago but with a different point of view.

I don't think the code is really necessary since it just makes the question a little less accurate but if only to see the structure I meant above in code here it goes.

The activity:

```
class ListEpisodes extends ListAbstract {

private long seriesId;              // Identifier of current Series
private String seriesTitle;         // Title of current Series

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a  {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory.
 * If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SeasonPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_episodes);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    try {
        seriesId = (Long) this.getIntent().getExtras().get("sid");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        seriesId = 0;
    }
    mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
    mDbAdapter.open();
    list();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_episodes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.create_new_episode:
            create();
            return true;
        case R.id.edit_series:
            editSeries();
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/////////////////////////////////////// ListAbstract ///////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Fetches and shows all episodes from the database.
 */
protected void list() {
    Cursor series = mDbAdapter.fetchSeries(seriesId);
    seriesTitle = series.getString(series.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.SERIES_KEY_TITLE));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(seriesTitle);

    Cursor eCursor = mDbAdapter.getSeasons(seriesId);
    ArrayList<Integer> seasons = new ArrayList<>();
    eCursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < eCursor.getCount(); i++) {
        seasons.add(eCursor.getInt(eCursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_SEASON_NUM)));
        eCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SeasonPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            seasons, seriesId);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

/**
 * Starts an activity to create a new episode.
 */
protected void create() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditEpisodes.class);
    i.putExtra(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_ID, Long.valueOf(0));
    i.putExtra(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_SERIES, seriesId);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

/**
 * Starts an activity to edit an episode.
 *
 * @param elementId id of the episode that will be edited.
 */
protected void edit(long elementId) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditEpisodes.class);
    i.putExtra(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_SERIES, seriesId);
    i.putExtra(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_ID, elementId);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

/**
 * Deletes the episode elementId.
 *
 * @param elementId id of the episode that will be deleted.
 */
protected void delete(long elementId) {
    // Episodes are refreshed if the current episode has been correctly deleted.
    if (mDbAdapter.deleteEpisode(elementId)) {
        list();
    }
}

/**
 * Starts an activity to edit the current series (with identifier [seriesId]).
 */
protected void editSeries() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditSeries.class);
    i.putExtra(DbAdapter.SERIES_KEY_ID, seriesId);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Fragment containing all episodes that correspond to the same season of a given
 * series.
 */
public static class SeasonFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * These arguments can only be passed via bundle. They match to season number and series Id.
     */
    private static final String ARG_TAB_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private static final String ARG_SERIES_ID = "series_id";
    private static final String ARG_SEASONS_ARRAY = "seasons_array";

    private ArrayList<Integer> seasons;
    private int season = -1;
    private int tab = -1;

    public SeasonFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given season.
     */
    protected static SeasonFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> seasons, int tabNumber,
                                                long seriesId) {
        SeasonFragment fragment = new SeasonFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putIntegerArrayList(ARG_SEASONS_ARRAY, seasons);
        args.putInt(ARG_TAB_NUMBER, tabNumber);
        args.putLong(ARG_SERIES_ID, seriesId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Fetches and shows all episodes on this fragment
     *
     * @param inflater           to instantiate the season view
     * @param container          to match the tabs (internal to android)
     * @param savedInstanceState argument container, since this class' constructor can't have
     *                           parameters
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DbAdapter mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this.getActivity());
        mDbAdapter.open();
        tab = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TAB_NUMBER);
        long series = getArguments().getLong(ARG_SERIES_ID);
        if (tab == 0) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_description, container, false);
            Cursor descriptionCursor = mDbAdapter.fetchSeries(series);
            //getActivity().startManagingCursor(descriptionCursor);
            String description = descriptionCursor.getString(
                    descriptionCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.SERIES_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(description);
            return rootView;
        } else {
            seasons = getArguments().getIntegerArrayList(ARG_SEASONS_ARRAY);
            assert seasons != null;
            season = seasons.get(tab - 1);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_episodes, container, false);
            // Get seriesId and fetch episodes for the season.
            Cursor episodes = mDbAdapter.fetchEpisodesFromSeason(getArguments().getLong(ARG_SERIES_ID),
                    season);
            //getActivity().startManagingCursor(episodes);
            EpisodeListViewAdapter adapter = new EpisodeListViewAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.episode_row, episodes, 0);
            ListView episodeList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.episode_list);
            episodeList.setAdapter(adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(episodeList);
            episodeList.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            toggleWatched(id);
                        }
                    });
            return rootView;
        }

    }

    private void toggleWatched(long episodeId) {
        DbAdapter mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this.getActivity());
        mDbAdapter.open();
        mDbAdapter.toggleWatched(episodeId);
        // Get seriesId and fetch episodes for the season.
        Cursor episodes = mDbAdapter.fetchEpisodesFromSeason(getArguments().getLong(ARG_SERIES_ID),
                season);
        ListView episodeList = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.episode_list);
        EpisodeListViewAdapter lva =  ((EpisodeListViewAdapter) episodeList.getAdapter());
        // Sometimes this works sometimes it doesn't
        lva.swapCursor(episodes);
        lva.notifyDataSetChanged();
        episodeList.setAdapter(lva);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates an options menu when a user clicks and holds on a series.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.clear();
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.edit_episode);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.delete_episode);
    }

    /**
     * Method called when a ContextMenu option is selected.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == DELETE_ID) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                    (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            ((ListAbstract) getActivity()).delete(info.id);
            return true;
        } else if (i == EDIT_ID) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                    (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            ((ListAbstract) getActivity()).edit(info.id);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Adapter class specific to populate the listView in ListSeries from a cursor.
     */
    static class EpisodeListViewAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
        public EpisodeListViewAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, layout, c, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor){
            super.changeCursor(cursor);
        }

        /**
         * Will be automatically called by android to populate the list view.
         * To do that it extracts the information from the cursor and transforms it to
         * something usable in the case of the rating images.
         */
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView numberView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.episode_number);
            String episode_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_EPISODE_NUM));
            numberView.setText(episode_number);

            TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.episode_name);
            String episode_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_NAME));
            if (episode_name.length() > 17) {
                try{
                    int cut = episode_name.indexOf(" ", 5);
                    episode_name = episode_name.substring(0, cut) + "\n" + episode_name.substring(cut + 1);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    episode_name = episode_name.substring(0,10)+"...";
                }
            }
            nameView.setText(episode_name);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.episode_watched);
            String wasWatched = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.EPISODE_KEY_WATCHED));
            wasWatched = wasWatched == null ? "0" : wasWatched;
            int watched_img = 0;
            switch (wasWatched) {
                case ("0"):
                    watched_img = R.drawable.unwatched;
                    break;
                case ("1"):
                    watched_img = R.drawable.watched;
                    break;
            }
            image.setImageResource(watched_img);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the seasons.
 */
protected class SeasonPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> seasons; // Holds all the seasons for the series
    private long seriesId;              // Id of the series

    public SeasonPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Integer> seasons, long seriesId) {
        super(fm);
        this.seasons = seasons;
        this.seriesId = seriesId;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int seasonNum) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return SeasonFragment.newInstance(seasons, seasonNum, seriesId);
    }

    /**
     * Forces all fragments to reload on update
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // There are more efficient implementations.
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    /**
     * @return amount of tabs in the view.
     */
    public int getCount() {
        // Since the description is in the first tab the count is one more
        // than the number of seasons
        return seasons.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // The first tab holds the description
        if (position == 0) return "Description";
        else {
            // The title contains the number of the season for the tab
            int season = seasons.get(position - 1);
            if (season >= 10) return "S" + season;
            else return "S0" + season;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The activity's layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(Content layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.ListEpisodes"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_list_episodes">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/series_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/series_description" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

A single row's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/EDot"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/episode_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/space"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/episode_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/episode_watched"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your fragmentpageradapter seems to be implemented in wrong way

Comment: @dex could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was here:

```
private void toggleWatched(long episodeId) {
    DbAdapter mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this.getActivity());
    mDbAdapter.open();
    mDbAdapter.toggleWatched(episodeId);
    // Get seriesId and fetch episodes for the season.
    Cursor episodes = mDbAdapter.fetchEpisodesFromSeason(getArguments().getLong(ARG_SERIES_ID),
            season);
    ListView episodeList = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.episode_list);
    EpisodeListViewAdapter lva =  ((EpisodeListViewAdapter) episodeList.getAdapter());
    // Sometimes this works sometimes it doesn't
    lva.swapCursor(episodes);
    lva.notifyDataSetChanged();
    episodeList.setAdapter(lva);
}
```

The line

```
ListView episodeList = (ListView)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.episode_list);
```

Was wrong and kind of unneccesary. This line would get some other ListView from (probably) the last fragment in view. So, I just stored the ListView I got from the intent on the fragment as a private variable and used it here.

Also, the original question here is doable. You'd just need to get change the ImageLayout in the view passed to the onClick method and change it's value from the image it has to the other.

To know what value it has at the time you can just use the method

```
setTag(R.drawable.theImage)
```

when the image resource is first set and then on toggle get the tag back and compare it to any resource and change it for the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter implementation i.e. after the `switch (wasWatched) {...` statement.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't do anything.